# Scroll down when the Scrollbar has no tag with Selenium for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to scroll down in an element, where the scrollbar doesnt have a tag/element. I did quite a few research on this but i couldnt find anything for that specific case. Im using Selenium for Python
We are talking about the Site "www.swap.gg", its a site for csgo skins, and in order to load every item from the bot, you need to scroll down in the element "Bot inventory". The Site looks like this when using F12 in browser it looks like this [The respective element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIR7N.png)

There is no key which you can use to scroll down there, therefore the `.send_keys()` command doesnt work by any chance. I also tried the `touchactions.scroll_from_element(element,xoffset,yoffset)` but didn't have any luck either. Im using Firefox as a webdriver incase that matters.
The xpath of the element is "/html/body/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIR7N.png)/section[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIR7N.png)/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]"
The CSS selector is "div.is-paddingless:nth-child(3)"
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Find the parent div

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/section[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]')
  ```
- Scroll down to trigger the reload

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 500)", element)
  ```

---

```
import selenium
import selenium.webdriver
import time

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://swap.gg/')

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/section[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]')
for i in range(20):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 500)", element)
    time.sleep(2)
```